# ASP classic - alternatives to enabling parent paths when installation directory unknown

Tags: asp-classic, server-side-includes

I'm continuing development on an ASP Classic web application. It makes heavy use of virtual directories to serve the core application to multiple users on different websites.

In order that these users have a choice of where to install the application (root or otherwise) parent paths are enabled so that relative server side includes can be used without using the root notation and virtual includes. So if I am in the administrator virtual folder and need access to a functions file or something I use the following to traverse up the tree one step then back down into the virtual folder that contains the file I need;

```
<!--#include file="../one-of-the-virtual-folders/file-i-need.asp" -->
```

I cant use;

```
<!--#include virtual="/one-of-the-virtual-folders/file-i-need.asp" -->
```

as the virtual folder maybe running in a sub directory and actually be

```
<!--#include virtual="/subdirectory/one-of-the-virtual-folders/file-i-need.asp" -->
```

I know this at runtime as where the application is being run from is a global variable BUT includes are run before any executed code so Ive no way of letting the include statement know where the application is being run and so what the directory structure is.

Do any brighter people than me out there have any idea how I can avoid the use of parent paths..?

Rolf

Comment: `<!--#include virtual="/path-to-folder/file-you-need.asp" -->` should find your file whether the path is via a virtual or a physical folder. Scroll down this page to the subheading "The Virtual Keyword" http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I understand using virtual and root relative paths. My issue is that the location from root is variable but I cant inlcude any variable or code in a server side include as it is processed before any code is run so something like ;

<!--#include virtual="/" & myInstallationDir & "one-of-the-virtual-folders/file-i-need.asp" -->

wont work. The application is shared via virtual folders to many installations.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the Server.Execute method? http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_execute.asp

Comment: @RolfHerbert Personally I would use parent paths as the `Server.Execute()` is overkill and limited more than includes.

Comment: Yes I am aware of server.execute but these include files are classes and helper functions that sort of thing which as far as I am aware wont work as it executes the code but wont let me access any functions within it.

Comment: Lankymart I am starting to think the same. If I move the entire application aware from the system drive then in the worst case scenario traversal across the drive will be impossible.

Comment: If you are using a virtual directory, then that virtual directory will get its own Application pool.   This kinda makes it isolated and includes dont work properly.   A workaround is giving iuser full permisions to the most parent path.